# the value of point member variable while assigning one object to another

Tags: c++, pointers, assign

If two objects of the same class are defined, one is assigned to the other.And the class has point member variable.For example,

```
class A{
private:
  int *a;
public:
  A(int x):a(&x){};
};
int main()
{
  int x = 2;
  A v_(x);
  A W_(v_);
  return 0;
}
```

then if `a` in `v_` points to the same address as `a` in `w_`?
Thanks if anyone can help me.

Comment: Yes, the both point to `x`. What's your question?

Comment: Thanks, I just think this is dangerous if there is coupling between different objects.

Comment: Another way to put that is that `W_.a` has the same value as `v_.a`. (There is nothing special about pointers; it works exactly the same as if it were an `int`.)

Comment: @rain-whalesong Uhm... ok. But what is your question?

Comment: `x` is passed by value thus your code does not make sense and has undefined behavior. Read a book or two on C++!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, they both point to same address.
[godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mcej8h) (using `%p` to print pointer address)

Reason for that is that the default copy constructor of `A` is called and all member values are copied to the new object (this include the value of the `a` that contains the address)

Comment: Thanks. And is there any practical application scenario for this?

Comment: practical application scenario for what exactly?

default Copy constructor assumes that all members can be freely copied.

If you have other requirements or limitations you can either delete copy constructor (that way you can no longer create another instance by calling with existing one) or provide your own copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4sTM6o